# Error while compiling signed apk (release build) in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

How to fix this issue while compiling release build in Android Studio 3.0

> Error:Error: json defines classes that conflict with classes now
>   provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or
>   alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example,
>   for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or
>   repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
>   [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

Here's the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.27.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.0.0'
compile 'com.arifian.networkstatelistener:lib:1.0.0'
compile 'com.arifian.view:centeredtoolbar:1.0.5'
compile 'com.sherlockshi.widget:aspectratioimageview:1.0.1'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.2.2'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.4'
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
compile 'com.wefika:horizontal-picker:1.1.1'
compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.1.4'
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.5.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'

}
```

Comment: Hi, I am also getting the same Issue when I update my AndroidStudio to 3.0.I have tried different solutions but I cannot able to solve my issue.Can you please help me ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: At this line "org.json:json:20160212" showing error  -  Error:(51) Error: json defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar. [DuplicatePlatformClasses]
       while creating Signed APK from AndroidStudio.Please help me.Thanks in Advance